# Why is pushState disrupted when using ng-include?

Tags: angularjs, pushstate, angularjs-ng-include

When using `ng-include`, the `pushState` function is disrupted.

The following is a simple example of this.

```
<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="angularCtrl">
    <div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
    <button ng-click="bye()">BYE</button>
</div>
```

and

```
let app = angular.module('angularApp', []);
app.controller('angularCtrl', async function ($scope) {
    $scope.templateUrl = '/assets/hi.html';
    $scope.bye = function () {
        $scope.templateUrl = '/assets/bye.html';
        history.pushState({},'','/finish.html')
    };
});
```

We want to change the body value after pressing the `BYE` button using `ng-include` and also change the page address by `pushState`.
This example is part of a larger project that has been simplified here as much as possible.

**Note:** According to the reviews, the url is changed by pushState but immediately returns its value. It is ignored during the ng-include process.

Comment: How do I get help from professionals? Unfortunately no one has answered this question and I need an answer. :(

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you expect (or would like) to happen? What do you mean by disrupted in this case? Also what do you mean by "pushState ... immediately returns its value"?

Comment: I want to change the `url` address `(pushState)`, in addition to changing the appearance `(Ng-include)`.
The `URL` is changed correctly. But after the appearance changes, the `url` returns to the previous value.
Suppose:  I'm on the "/about-us" page. I want to change the address to "/contact-us" after clicking a button. The appearance will also be changed using the ng-include.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the browser location is inherently tricky in AngularJS. It is best to try to use the `$location` service as much as possible as this understands and works with the `$scope` digest machinery better.

Try using the following in your app:

```js
let app = angular.module('angularApp', []);
app.config(function ($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

app.controller('angularCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $location) {
    $scope.templateUrl = '/assets/hi.html';
    $scope.bye = function () {
        $scope.templateUrl = '/assets/bye.html';
        $location.url('/finish.html');
    };
});
```

Note that you will need to provide a `base[href]` for html5 mode support:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ...
  <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="angularCtrl">
    <div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
    <button ng-click="bye()">BYE</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```